# Question on GL(n,F) representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let A be the group of all invertible n x n matrices over F, A+/- the subgroups of all upper/lower matrices.

1. F^n as an A-module is irreducible? Is this because F^n has only one orbit under A?
2. Why is F^n indecomposable but not irreducible as an A+ or A- module? Is this statement equivalent to some theorem in linear algebra?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. To be fair, it has two orbits, $0$ being one of them. But your reasoning is right.

Comment: 2. I assume you assume $n \geq 2$ here. Try finding a nonzero proper $A^+$-submodule...

Comment: Use the face that dim(eigenspace) of a triangular matrix = number of distinct diagonal entries?

Comment: You don't need to use any facts here.

Comment: So are you suggesting that there is some slick one-line proof of this statement? Can you please give me some hints? Thanks?

Comment: What do upper-triangular matrices do to the first vector of the standard basis ($e_1$)?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Just realize how dumb this question is. Should have started with concrete computations instead of looking for abstract theorems in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is for part $2$.

First, we have the following $A^+$-submodules of $F^n$

$$V_k = \textrm{span}\{ e_i \ | \ 1\le i \le k\}$$

for all $0\le k \le n$, with $V_0 = (0)$, $V_n = F^n$ and $\dim V_k = k$ for all $k$. We will prove there are no other $A^+$ submodules.  Consider the following element of $A^+$, $g= I +n$, where $n(e_i) = e_{i-1}$, $n( e_1) = 0$. In fact, we can show that any subspace $W$ of $F^n$ invariant under $g$ equals one of the $V_k$. Indeed, let $k$  be the smallest index so that $V_k \supset W$. Then $W$ contains an element of the form $v = a_k e_k + a_{k-1} e_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1 e_1$, with $a_k \ne 0$. Now every subspace invariant under $g = I +n$ is also invariant under $n$. Therefore $v$,$n(v)$, $n^2(v)$, $\ldots$, $n^{k-1}(v)$ are in $W$. But these $k$ vectors form a basis of $V_k$. Therefore $W\supset V_k$ and so $W=V_k$.

We have determined all the $A^{+}$-submodules of $F^n$. We see that they are totally ordered by inclusion and so they cannot decompose $F^n$ in a nontrivial way.